# python( tkinter)を使ってキャンバスに画像が認識されない

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle

アプリ(script.py)を実行してもキャンバスに画像(script2.png)が描画されない

アプリ(script.py),　画像（scipt2.png）は同じフォルダに入っている

Comment: で、どんなプログラムを実行したのですか？
プログラムの内容が判らないと回答しようがないので、script.pyの内容を質問に追加してください。

Comment: 質問者さんはその後ここを訪れていない(マルチポストも無さそう)ようですが、こんな記事を参考に質問自身も改善してほしいところです。[canvasに画像が表示されない](https://teratail.com/questions/178304), [PythonのCanvasに画像が表示されない](https://teratail.com/questions/85640), [Tkinter canvas not showing image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41014005/9014308), [関数内で画像を表示できない問題 Python/tkinterプログラミング](https://www.ooub.net/archives/log362)